# Haskell - lacks accompanying binding,

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

I'm currently completing a project to create a film rating system / database using Haskell.

I'm trying to add the functionality that allows the user to become a fan of a film.

I have:

```
isFan :: Fan -> Film -> Bool
isFan givenFan (_, _, _, fans) = any (\fan -> fan == givenFan) fans

filmsWithFan :: Fan -> [Film]
filmsWithfan givenFan = filter (isFan givenFan) testDatabase
```

But this is bringing up an error saying that: The type signature for 'filmswithFan' lacks accompanying binding.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
filmsWithFan :: Fan -> [Film]
--       ^ upper case F
filmsWithfan givenFan = filter (isFan givenFan) testDatabase
--       ^ lower case f
```

Whenever you see a "type signature lacks accompanying binding" message, **carefully** check your function names for typos.

Answer (score 1):

You capitalised the function name differently in the two lines, `filmsWithFan` vs`filmsWithfan`